# Feasibility of insulation under roof decking and whole-attic insulation with closed cell

Tags: insulation, attic, spray-foam

So this question is actually two parts.  We have a 5 in 12 hip roof (one gable actually) with old corrugated tin on lathe.  Everything lies on 2x4 truss rafters.  We will be removing everything, laying plywood or OSB decking, and adding new continuous metal panels in replacement.

I have not seen this done but am considering adding a layer of that pink Owens Corning 1" thick insulation under the plywood decking and using long screws, while I have the opportunity.  It seems logical to get this done while everything is off - I can get a good tight seal.

So the next question is the feasibility of insulating the rafters vs. the joists.  I plan to have the HVAC system up there (already did that on another house) and don't mind spraying on more foam to attach to the 1" boards that will be there already.  However a friend of mine says our area (Austin TX) is too humid and the attic needs to breathe, and have ridge vents etc..  I'm inclined to disagree, insulated space is insulated space and I will have CO detectors and etc. up there.  So again, the question here is the feasibility of a whole-attic insulation system attached to the rafters.  Thanks!

Comment: Usually place all insulation above the ceiling to insulate the living space.  Let attic have as much ventilation as possible, air coming in from lowest place and exits though the top.  Roof deck needs ventilation or it cooks.

Comment: I think what OP described is fairly common for cathedral ceilings.

Comment: @SteveSh that was exactly my thought, if the humidity rule was true then you should never have vaulted ceilings in a house.

Comment: A warm roof design (i.e. insulation at rafter level) is perfectly workable in all climate zones provided you correctly manage vapour. The build show on YT is in Texas and has plenty of free info on how to detail such a roof if you need guidance.

Comment: [Building a BETTER attic - Unvented + Conditioned attics 101](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XjI8HyUqe4w)